# Wrapper for HTTP response encoding

Tags: c++, http, encoding, response, wrapper

I don't want create new wheel and try to found wrappers for encoding HTTP response for C or C++ (or may be Java implementation).

I search something like this :

```
HttpResponse resp(HttpResponse::Ok_200);
resp.addHeader(someHeaderName, someHeaderValue);
resp.addPart(somePart);
std::string src; // or std::ostream src
resp.write(src);
```

Do you know something ?

Answer (score 2):

[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html)

Answer (score 1):

I once tried the [ClanLib](http://clanlib.org/) HTTP implementation and it looked a lot like your suggestion. As far as I can remember, I used the [CL_HTTPClientConnection](http://clanlib.org/docs/clanlib-2.2/reference/CL_HTTPClientConnection.html) and the [CL_HTTPServerConnection](http://clanlib.org/docs/clanlib-2.2/reference/CL_HTTPServerConnection.html).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/documentation/index.html) libraries include very good HTTP support - see eg http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPResponse.html.